# Standalone C application

Tags: c, gtk, gnuplot

I've a project completely coded in C with dependencies on gnuplot, gtk, GNU Scientific Library, etc. It works fine on my machine.

However, how can I package it as a standalone executable which would be platform and OS independent?

Even if it works for any Linux platform, it's fine.

Comment: If you want platform independance, you need to run it in a virtual machine of some kind. The JVM is the reason that Java is so cross-platform. You can't have the same binary run directly on an x86 Linux system as you have on an ARM Linux system. You could stick your application in a VirtualBox machine that you can distribute, but that includes the whole OS. You couldn't run it in Docker the way it is on Linux because that runs on the host kernel instead of in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

> However, how can I package it as a standalone executable which would be platfrom and OS independent?

You can't. At least the standard C library has to use OS-specific APIs (syscalls, library functions) at many places.

> Even if it works for any Linux platform, it's fine.

Linux is kind of a moving target, still this is often possible by linking all the libraries statically -- see your compiler's documentation for how to do that.

Comment: Assuming the target platform supports some specific blackbox environment like docker, node, etc., can something similar be done in this case?

Comment: Better to look in the linker documentation, as linking statically is not a compiler issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have something a C program run on different OSes without recompiling.

This being said, if you want to compile your your program for a single platform like Linux, static compilation may usually be a solution, but it's not a use case handled by GTK+, so you might be able to build the other dependencies statically, but GTK+ and its dependencies will need to be built dynamically and shipped separately.

Usually you'd then be advised to package your application for your GNU/Linux distro of choice using RPM/DEB packages, but that would work for only that one distro.

So the best choice I see is to use [flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) to bundle your dependencies, and have flatpak installed where you want to install your app.